# What determines Ranald's Gift?

Tags: warhammer-vermintide-2

Ranald's Gift seemingly gives random amounts of progress towards loot boxes. What determines how much progress you get?  Or is it purely RNG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ranald's logo is a finger crossed sign: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossed_fingers which is mostly used as a sign to wish for luck. As such Ranald's blessing is all pure luck and RNG.

Comment: Although this seems to be the obvious answer to many of us, it is still speculation. Do we have any official word or indication from the developers to support this?

Comment: @Alex In Warhammer Fantasy RPG rulebooks, Ranald is the god of luck and mischief in human pantheon.

Answer (score 1):

It uses an RNG. It will generate a random number from 0% to 150% of the progress bar. Depending on your points, Ranald's Gift can improve the loot boxes you get by up to two tiers higher.

| Item | Points (1 bar = 100 points) |
| --- | --- |
| Mission Success | 50 |
| Quickplay Bonus | 50 |
| Tomes | 50 each |
| Grimoires | 75 each |
| Loot Dice | 25 each |
| Ranald's Gift | random number from 0 to 150 |

Table source: [Vermintide 2 Wiki, "Loot" article](https://vermintide2.fandom.com/wiki/Loot#Box_Tiers)